# How do I reorder column groups on SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm having issues with some column grouping on an SSRS report I'm working on. Essentially at the moment, the report is designed to pull two broad categories, let's say Category 1 and Category 2. But underneath, there can be more than one value in those categories.

Currently the column group on the report shows category 1 before category 2. However, I want to show category 2 before category 1 which is fine, but at the moment it displays the last value from category 2 first. However, I want to show the first value from category 2 first, and then 2,3 etc and the same order for category 1 after.

For example, Category 1 has values A, B and C and Category 2 has values D, E and F.

Currently, I've switched the sort order on the report to Z > A for the category, and it now shows Category 2: F,E D and then Category 1: C, B and A.

However, I want it to show Category 2: D, E and F and then Category 1: A, B and C. I'm not sure if I can use the SQL ROW_NUMBER() function in the SQL query itself, but at the moment, I'm not having much luck.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

In you top (parent) category group you can use an expression to handle the group order such as.

```
=IIF(Fields!Category.Value = "Category2", 1, 2)
```

If you put this in you sort expression rather than using a specific column this will evaluate for each `Category` column and return 1 if it's "category2" or 2 if it's not. Sort direction should be the default A-Z

For the child column group you can just use your "subcategory" (not sure what it's really called) and group A-Z as normal.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the help. I tried using this expression, and I've managed to get it in the order I want for Category 2. I.e. D, E and F but for Category 1, it's still showing the values in reverse order (C, B and A). Would I need to create a separate child group for Category 1? Both Category 1 and 2 are from the same column in the SQL database, could I use a 'then by' custom sort on the same column group? Many thanks

Comment: Not to worry, I've managed to solve it. Thanks for your help :)